# How can I get Geany to show me the methods a library has when I press the '.' key?

Tags: python, ide, intellisense, geany

In visual studio, I could just press ctrl+spacekey and the methods appeared. In Geany is there a way for me to get this functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because is Python is dynamically typed language and quite hard to achieve that. Python plugins for netbeans do that partially, but I believe such plugin is not in geany developers plans. There are different things to be done ;-)

However, geany provides some completions support. First, it analyzes your imports in a file and uses it in completions; furthermore it completes functions from the std library. It also analyzes all you open files for suggestions, although you may need to apply it in preferences. Also you can get call tips, when you hit **Ctrl+Shift+Space**, which not everyone know about. They are quite good, because they appear in form `<Class>.<method>(<args>)`, which is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

shortcut `ctrl+space` works for me. also, you can setup autocomplete suggestion length  (ie how many letters you must type before the autocomplete tooltip pops up automatically - http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#editor-completions-preferences ).

this works only for method names. if i want to see the options for method parameters, i must type bracket `(` after the method full name.